# How to evaluate the integral $\int_1^2{\frac{\arctan{x}}{x^2-x+1} \, dx}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to evaluate the following integral: $\int\limits_1^2{\dfrac{\arctan{x}}{x^2-x+1}dx}$?

I tried to make a substitution $t = \arctan{x}$, but it didn't help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to WA it cannot be evaluated in terms of elementary functions. A very complicated-looking answer.

Comment: Why was the feynman trick answer deleted?